What is the point in showing which post(s) was/were handled incorrectly in the suspension message, if you can't review your own reviews?
Today, I got a message that I was suspended from the staging ground. The message shows me a list of questions I've apparently handled incorrectly. This list contains actual URL's towards the specific handled question(s). However I'm unable to review my own review(s) because of the suspension.
What's the point of adding a list of URL's in the suspension message, if you can't click them and review the action(s) taken? The end of the suspension message even states to "revist recent reviews", which is impossible.

You’ve been suspended from reviewing. You will be able to review again tomorrow.
The following Staging Ground posts were handled incorrectly:

I want to implement Google Authenticator code login on my Adobe ColdFusion and Javascript website. Is it possible?
How to change my website past-login to contain account-related stuff?
Delphi : Is there an equivalent for FireMonkey to the RGB(Red, Green, Blue) in Windows Unit?

[ ... ]
In the meantime, you can refer to the help center for more information and revisit your recent reviews.


I've omitted the suspension reason, because I'm not trying to argue with the reason of the suspension, I just want to re-check the question(s) in the proposed list and see whether I was in the wrong and/or what I could've done better.

Going on a bit of a tangent here, but if you want to discuss certain SG posts and how they should be reviewed, etc. feel free to hop into the Staging Ground Discussion/Support chat.

No, that's not the question at hand. What's the purpose of a showing a list with URL's which you can't access? I'm not here to discuss the posts shown in the message.

Uh, I did say the comment was tangential to your question. (I do agree with the question, suspended users should be able to see their reviews)

That's quite unfortunate. Would this possibly qualify as a bug?

If you want to see the linked questions, here are screenshots: first question second question third question

This seems like a bug to me, so I'm tagging it as such and escalating for staff review.

Questions that say "is X possible?" should usually just be edited to say "how do I X?" instead. Obviously nobody would ask without wanting to be able to do it, which entails finding out how to do it.

Not the point of the post, but - the first one should be "major changes" instead of "off-topic" (it's too broad, not asking for off-site resource), the second one doesn't look off-topic (again, "too broad" should get "major changes" instead of "off-topic"), and the third one isn't asking for software recommendations since they're looking for a function, not a library/tutorial/etc.

@Anerdw FWIW you can have 2-3 different voters each voting a different way, and the result is always a single closure reason. I've personally voted something as off-topic wholly on the post being entirely "opinion-based", yet the closure reason was a duplicate because a previous voter voted that way. There's simply not enough information here to say DarkBee was the individual that voted closed these posts as "seeking off-site resources....".

@DrewReese still, in SG Major Changes are for when the question can be edited to be on-topic. On main you have a similar thing with closures, where it's a temporary state until edited. However, SG is not the main site.

@DrewReese In my experience, a "seeks off-site resources" or "opinion-based" banner in the Staging Ground only occurs if there is concensus between the off-topic voters (or the other one selects the "Duplicate" option maybe. Otherwise it would be a more general banner AFAIK (but I could be wrong on that).

@dan1st I was specifically referring to SG. I've personally voted close a post as "off-topic - opinion-based" and because a previous voter voted to close as a duplicate, the post was closed as a duplicate. I've considered filing this behavior as a bug, but since the goal is non-publication either way I've not been too bothered by it.

@VLAZ You are preaching to the choir, I've been involved in SG since beta 1. In any case, whenever some SG issue has come up and I argue as you have stated, that "Major Changes are for when the question can be edited to be on-topic" it seems others want to instead flag for R/A, or Mod intervention, etc... and then someone will post that they did exactly that, flagging, and the flags were declined because "that's what SG is for", to edit until publishable. ‍♂️ Your link, it's funny, Braiam is often very vocal about "SG issues", yet I don't seem them very active there.

@DrewReese Moderators can see individual actions. So regardless of what the summary on the close notice is (SG or regular questions) moderator actions are based on the particular actions of some user.

There is also one significant difference between regular questions and SG. In SG questions closed as off-topic or opinion based are removed from the list of active questions. That prevents them from being seen by other users who are possibly looking for SG questions in their area of expertise. So "Major changes" is way better option most of the time as it gives asker the opportunity to improve and allows more people to interact with it besides the ones who did the review.

@DalijaPrasnikar I think you might've misunderstood the point I was making to Anerdw. Non-mods can't "see individual actions.", so it's pointless to assume attribution of the final closure resolution to the OP here.

@DrewReese Yes, non-mods cannot see individual actions, so assumption of OP action could be wrong, but the suggestion how those questions should have been handled was correct one. I also wanted to emphasize that moderators have more information about individual actions.
